# Django all related data

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Docs(models.Model):
    doc_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    journal = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'docs'

class Assays(models.Model):
    assay_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    doc = models.ForeignKey('Docs', models.DO_NOTHING)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'assays'

class Activities(models.Model):
    activity_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    assay = models.ForeignKey(Assays, models.DO_NOTHING)
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Docs, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    record = models.ForeignKey('CompoundRecords', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'activities'
```

I apologize in advance if this answer is easily found elsewhere. I have searched all over and do not see a simple way to query my data as intuitively as I feel like should be possibe.

These are classes for 3 tables. The actual dataset is closer to 100 tables. Each doc_id can have one or many associated activity_ids. Each activity_id is associated with one assay_id.

My goal is to obtain all of the related data for each of the activities in a single doc. For instance:

```
query_activities_values = Docs.objects.get(doc_id=5535).activities_set.values()
for y in query_activities_values:
    print(y)
    break
>>> {'activity_id': 753688, 'assay_id': 158542, 'doc_id': 5535, .....
```

This returns 32 dictionaries (only part of the first is shown) for columns in the Activities table that have doc_id=5535. I would like to go one step further and also automatically pull in all of the data from the Assays table that is associated with the corresponding assay_id for each dictionary.

I can access that Assay data through a similar query, but only by stating each field explicitly:

```
query_activities_values = Docs.objects.get(doc_id=5535).activities_set.values('assay', 'assay__assay_type', 'assay__description')
for y in query_activities_values:
    print(y)
    break
```

I would like a single query that finds not only the assay and associated assay data for one activity_id, but finds all data and associated data for the 90+ other tables associated in the model

Thank you

**Update 1**

I did find this code that works surprisingly well for my needs, however, I was curious if this is the best method:

`from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
def serial_model(modelobj):
  opts = modelobj._meta.fields
  modeldict = model_to_dict(modelobj)
  for m in opts:
    if m.is_relation:
        foreignkey = getattr(modelobj, m.name)
        if foreignkey:
            try:
                modeldict[m.name] = serial_model(foreignkey)
            except:
                pass
  return modeldict`

That's not too much code, but I thought there may be a more built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is prefetch_related:

[Django 2.2 Prefetch Related Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
query_activities_values = Docs.objects.get(doc_id=5535).activities_set.values()
```

Would become:

```
query_activities_values = Docs.objects.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch("activities_set", to_attr="activities"), models.Prefetch("assays_set", to_attr="assays")).get(doc_id=5535)
```

A new attributes will be created called "activities" and "assays" which you can use to retrieve data.

One more thing. This isn't actually 1 query. It's 3. However, if you're getting more than just one object from Docs, it's still going to be 3.

Also, is there a reason why you're using BigIntegerField?

Comment: Thanks! Firstly, no, there's no particular reason I'm using BigIntegerField. This is a legacy database and that is what inspectdb assigned. I read those should be changed, but I had not looked far enough into that yet as it did not seem to be interfering with anything. So I understand that using prefetch_related caches those explicitly defined attributes, however, they must still be called explicitly. With a large web of connected tables, there is a lot of code involved with explicitly defining every linked table and explicitly querying each of those.

Comment: I posted an update above. Apologies if you're getting a lot of notifications. I was struggling with the code formatting in the comments and just read to post my code as an update in the original question rather than in a comment. Thanks again.